# Se excedió limite de memoria (JVM)

Tags: java, excel, tomcat, struts2

Estoy realizando mantenimiento a una web, donde me encontré con este error:

> "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"

Esto sucede cuando se ejecuta un reporte con *javapoi* y *struts2*; revisando la clase de implementación, prácticamente es un código bastante simple :

```
    public String reporteGerencias() throws SQLException {
     String fpath = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/excel/reporteGerencias.xlsx"); 
        pdfName = "\\resultadopoi";
        rpt = "reporteGerencias.xlsx";
        ModeloExcelBI mg = new ModeloExcelBI();
        List<ReportesGraficos> ListarMuestrasReportesBI = mg.ListarReporteGerencia(fechaInicio, fechaFin);
        List<ReportesGraficos> ListarMuestrasReportesBIGe = mg.ListarReporteGerenciaAcumulado(fechaInicio, fechaFin);
        
        try {
        
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fpath));
              Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fileInputStream);
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            
            for (int i = 0; i < ListarMuestrasReportesBIGe.size(); i++) {
                 ReportesGraficos reports2 = (ReportesGraficos)ListarMuestrasReportesBIGe.get(i);
                    Row row = sheet.getRow(3 + i);
                           
                    row.getCell(1).setCellValue(reports2.getContmetal());
                    row.getCell(2).setCellValue(reports2.getTmss());
                    row.getCell(3).setCellValue(reports2.getValorizacion());
                    row.getCell(4).setCellValue(reports2.getDeduccion());
                    row.getCell(5).setCellValue(reports2.getTotalliqui());
                    row.getCell(6).setCellValue(reports2.getLeyy());
                    row.getCell(7).setCellValue(reports2.getSgr());
                    row.getCell(8).setCellValue(reports2.getLiquirelley());
                       
                    row.getCell(10).setCellValue(reports2.getMargens());
                    row.getCell(11).setCellValue(reports2.getHumedades());
                    row.getCell(12).setCellValue(reports2.getTmh2());
                    
                    row.getCell(13).setCellValue(reports2.getMargenpor());
      
            }
          
            
            
            
             for (int i = 0; i < ListarMuestrasReportesBI.size(); i++) {
                 ReportesGraficos report = (ReportesGraficos)ListarMuestrasReportesBI.get(i);
                    Row row = sheet.getRow(9 + i);
                       
                    row.getCell(0).setCellValue(report.getTipo());
                   
                    row.getCell(1).setCellValue(report.getLote());
                    row.getCell(2).setCellValue(report.getLiquidacion());
                    row.getCell(3).setCellValue(report.getGuia());
                    row.getCell(4).setCellValue(report.getFecha());
                    row.getCell(5).setCellValue(report.getNombre());
                    row.getCell(6).setCellValue(report.getZona());
                    row.getCell(7).setCellValue(report.getVeta());
                    row.getCell(8).setCellValue(report.getNivel());
                    row.getCell(9).setCellValue(report.getPlaca());
                    // Calculos Celdas
                    row.getCell(10).setCellValue(report.getTmss());
                    row.getCell(11).setCellValue(report.getLeyy());
                    row.getCell(12).setCellValue(report.getLiquirelley());
                    
                    row.getCell(13).setCellValue(report.getSgr());
                    row.getCell(14).setCellValue(report.getValorizacion());
                    row.getCell(15).setCellValue(report.getDeduccion());
                    row.getCell(16).setCellValue(report.getTotalliqui());
                    row.getCell(17).setCellValue(report.getMargenpor());
                    row.getCell(18).setCellValue(report.getMargens());
                    row.getCell(19).setCellValue(report.getHumedades());
                    row.getCell(20).setCellValue(report.getLiquidacion());
                    row.getCell(21).setCellValue(report.getCentrocosto());
                   // row.getCell(20).setCellValue(report.getCentrocosto());
                   
            }
             HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
                response.setContentType(excel_xlsx);
                try (OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
                     response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=reporteGerencias.xlsx");
                    wb.write(out);
                }
            
            

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

Están utilizando *tomcat*; así que al entrar al "**status**" del servidor de *tomcat* y ver cuánta memoria de *JVM* tiene asignada me doy con la sorpresa que son **228 MB**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna persona que pudiera comentarme como puedo aumentar la memoria del *JVM* del *tomcat* ?. De ante mano agradezco todo su apoyo

Comment: ¿Cuál versión de tomcat y en qué sistema operativo?

Comment: Tomcat 7 y windows server 2012

Answer (score 0):

La primer recomendación es que si usas `XSSFWorkbook` mejor uses [`SXSSFWorkbook`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html), el segundo es más eficiente con el manejo de memoria.

Para aumentar la memoria de Tomcat, en el archivo `<tomcat>/bin/setenv.bat` (créalo si no existe) agrega la línea:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS="%CATALINA_OPTS% -Xmx512M"
```

Ajusta el valor de Xmx (ó Xms ó MaxPermSize) según tus necesidades.